# Social.framework doesn't work for Xcode 6.3.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, twitter

As a newbie i wanted to try out Facebook and Twitter Post using objective-c

So i added 2 buttons, added actions to it, also added social framework. When i run the code and click on Tweet or Facebook Buttons nothing happens, am i missing something.I am testing it on Simulator, does that make any difference.

Here is my header file SocialSharingViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SocialSharingViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)postToTwitter:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)postToFacebook:(id)sender;

@end
```

Here is my .m file SocialSharingViewController.m

```
#import "SocialSharingViewController.h"
#import <Social/Social.h>

@interface SocialSharingViewController ()

@end

@implementation SocialSharingViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)postToTwitter:(id)sender {
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                               composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Great fun to learn iOS programming"];
        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (IBAction)postToFacebook:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"clicked facebook button");
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [controller setInitialText:@"First post from my iPhone app"];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Comment: Are you testing on iPhone or simulator?

Comment: @YunusErenGüzel I am testing it on simulator

Comment: If you are sure that the `isAvailable` methods are reachable you should test it on an actual phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things come to mind:

- Did you connect the buttons in your .xib to the `IBAction` methods in your code?
- Is `-isAvailableForServiceType:` legitimately returning `NO`, preventing them from showing?

Comment: 1) Yes the buttons are connected in storyboard. (2) how do i check if -isAvailableForServiceType: legitimately returning NO ?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and see if your if statement is being entered. That method might not be available in the simulator or something.